# How to catch and potential 301 or 404 errors when appropriate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, seo, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

We had a little mishap where an https binding was created for a website without a hostname (just an ip), and then another website was created with only an http binding to a hostname using the same ip as the first site.

So the problem is when you navigate to the 2nd site over https, instead of getting an error it just goes to the first website. As a result Google was able to access the first site through the 2nd sites host name over https and now we have lots of duplicate links out in google land.

I've already stopped the bleeding, but now I need to 301 all the bad links that were created by Google for the 2nd site. My plan is that, going forward, anytime a 404 error is encountered in the 2nd site then it will call for just the header from the same link on the 1st site. If the header returns with an OK status then it will do a permanent redirect to the 1st site.

There's just one part of that plan I don't know how to do off the top of my head... what's the best way to intercept the 404s in such a way I can run my code to determine whether it should be 301'd or not?

Comment: An alternate solution for you to consider would be the use of canonical urls - https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html . This will avoid duplicate URLs being indexed.

Comment: We do actually... but didn't hardcore the host :/ will do so now though.